# How to fetch account email using Outlook REST API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, outlook, outlook-restapi

There is outdated tutorial in Ruby - https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/tutorial/ruby
( search for get_email_from_id_token in the .\o365-tutorial\app\helpers\auth_helper.rb file )

First of all - I tried it and it does not work.

I tried to make request for profile:

```
conn = Faraday.new(url: 'https://outlook.office.com') do |faraday|
  # Outputs to the console
  faraday.response :logger
  # Uses the default Net::HTTP adapter
  faraday.adapter  Faraday.default_adapter
end

response = conn.get do |request|
  # Get events from the calendar
  request.url '/api/v2.0/Me'
  request.headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer #{token}"
  request.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'
end

JSON.parse(response.body)
```

It returns user profile data, but email field is blank. It is strange.

Did anyone face/solve this problem ?

Comment: Could you show the response you get? What is the result of `JSON.parse(response.body)` ?

Comment: @SriVishnuTotakura sorry, I receive UserName email for one account, but other account has empty email and it scares me. I will contact outlook REST API support